# Testing dropdown list using WatiN

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, watin

I am using WatiN to test a website and automate a process.  I can successfully open the website, however an issue arises when I am trying to select an option from a select list:

```
<select id="form:Dropdown" name="form:Dropdown" size="1" title="Select Option"> <option value="0">Select Code</option>
    <option value="234890/NA/1">23FA4890</option>
    <option value="237014/NA/1">23FA7014</option>
</select>
```

Code:

```
            Settings.AttachToBrowserTimeOut = 240;
            Settings.WaitUntilExistsTimeOut = 240;
            Settings.WaitForCompleteTimeOut = 240;    

            browser = new IE();
            browser.GoTo(url);
            browser.WaitForComplete();
            //Thread.Sleep(10000);
            browser.SelectList(Find.ById("form:Dropdown")).WaitUntilExists(); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
            SelectList dList = browser.SelectList(Find.ById("form:Dropdown"));
            dList.Select("23FA4890");
```

This looks like it should work, but I keep getting an error "Timeout while waiting 240 seconds for element to show up."

Comment: Are you able to select it by the value (using `SelectByValue` method)?

Comment: @AdamPlocher The error is coming at the SelectList so I have not even tried selecting the option by value.

Comment: Just as another note - have you tried doing a `FindByName` to see if you get any better results?  I posted an answer below which may or may not help :)

Comment: @AdamPlocher Still not working.  Same error when I try FindByName.

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: @AdamPlocher IE8.0.7601

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to call `WaitUntilExists` since `WaitForComplete` is already going to block until the page is fully loaded.  I know this doesn't answer your question completely, but I wanted to show you an example of some code that I've been using in production for over a year that has never been a problem.

Note, I'm grabbing a frame from within an iframe and selecting the value of "ID" from the drop down list:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^.*\/globalframeset\.esp.*$");
using (var browser = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(regex), 12))
{
    if (browser != null)
    {
        browser.AutoClose = false;

        var iFrame = browser.Frame(Find.ById("GlobalWrapper"));

        if (iFrame != null)
        {
            var frame = iFrame.Frame(Find.ByName("frGlobalNav"));

            if (frame != null)
            {
                frame.TextField(Find.ByName("findtext")).Value = person.MedicalRecordNumber;

                // This code is setting the DDL called "filtertype" to a value of "ID"
                frame.SelectList(Find.ByName("filtertype")).SelectByValue("ID");

                Regex buttonRegex = new Regex(@"^.*\/go_text\.gif.*$");
                frame.Image(Find.BySrc(buttonRegex)).ClickNoWait();
            }
        }

        browser.BringToFront();
    }
}
```